# how do you change a variable for another variable in c?

Tags: c

im a beginner with a not so good teacher and trying to figure things out on my own...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int n,x,c,a;
main()
{
    scanf("%d",&n);
    do
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        a=x;
        c++;
    }
    while(c!=n);
    printf("%d",a);

}
```

in this code, i'd like to know if it's possible to change the 'a' in `(a=x;)` to, lets say 'b' then 'c', then 'd'.... i want to store the different values from `scanf("%d",&x);` in different variables.
Example, if i enter the values, 1,2,3,4, i'd like the output to be a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4

thanks for the help

Comment: Look up arrays. Check manual page for `scanf` for return values. Initialise variables

Comment: Be careful when using variables you are not explicitly initializing, for example `c`. It works now because global variables are zero-initialized, but if you make `c` a local variable it will *not* be initialized and `c` would have an indeterminate value, and using it uninitialized would lead to *undefined behavior*. And you really *should* make the variables local, having global variables is considered a big no-no by most.

Comment: thanks for the response, although there are some concepts you mentioned that i dont understand (beginner...). zero-initialized,uninitialized,undefined behavior,global variables. would you care to explain please? (it's ok if you dont, google and stuff...)

Comment: what he means is that you should assign a value to `c` before the `do/while` loop. Right now it works, but you should do it to avoid potential problems with it

Comment: oooh.... looking back, this makes sense. well, thanks, i'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you to use arrays, if your prof. will be ok with it.
And there is a question: do you want to just print it ? or change ..

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n[4];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("Enter 4 numbers");
        scanf("%d",&n[i]);  
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%c = %d\n",(97+i),n[i]);    
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of  (97+i) it would be better to write 'a' + i